# Alternatives to placeholder in combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a comobobox that I load through my viewmodel. The combobox will have a default blank selection once it appears, which naturally could be nicely covered with a placeholder text.

I have tried different things to achieve this, however since nothing seemed to achieve what I intended, Iended up using a library (xceed) that supports a watermark functionality in their extended combobox control.

However, if I reload the combobox with new entities, I'm back to a situation where a blank selection is made - I can however exapand the combobox to view my entities.

From a user point of view, this is not very nice. Which is why I want to know, how can I correctly add a placeholder text to my combobox, which will appear appear before and after i update the contents of my conbobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have your options in an IDictionary, maybe populated from a database.

So in your ViewModel you could do something like:

`IDictionary<int, string> items = GetComboOptions();
var comboDataSource = new Dictionary<int, string>({0,"Select..."}).Union(items).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);`

Then you need to bind it to your view by putting the code into a property perhaps. I haven't tested this code though.